# UI performance tax

Tags: ios, performance, user-interface

I have this loop on a background thread, of which I want to inform the user of its progress.

So, in this loop, I call

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBarto:) withObject:@(value) waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I put some logging before and after the loop, and made the following observations:

**If I enable** the above line in order to show **the progress**, my logging console shows:

```
2017-06-17 16:43:49.675 myApp[8523:551864] Start Import
2017-06-17 16:43:59.119 myApp[8523:551864] Done Importing
```

that's a delta of roughly **9.5 seconds**

**without the progress bar**, it looks like

```
2017-06-17 16:47:06.052 myApp[8611:556572] Start Import
2017-06-17 16:47:12.776 myApp[8611:556572] Done Importing
```

down to **6.7 seconds**

As a comparison, if the loop is run in a Background Fetch, where there is **no UI involved at all**, logging shows:

```
2017-06-17 16:45:12.199 myApp[8523:553684] Start Import
2017-06-17 16:45:13.084 myApp[8523:553684] Done Importing
```

which is **less than a second**.

if I set

```
waitUntilDone:NO
```

I get the unwanted side effect that the progress bar is update only 3 times, rather than 50+ times.

The technical question: is this something I/the user has to live with, or are there any perceptional tricks to solve this?

The psychological question:
Would you/the user prefer six seconds *without* visual feedback over 9 seconds *with* feedback?

Your insights are very welcome.

Comment: You are right that you should not wait. And, better, use GCD's `dispatch_async` rather than `performSelector` calls. But your numbers beg the question of why the progress bar updates are taking that much time. But we'd need to see what's going on there in order to comment. Simple progress bar updates should easily update more than 50 times over a 6 second process. There's something else going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you do the UI update async using the GDC. There should be very little overhead in the background thread and little latency in the UI:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateProgressBarto:@(value)];
    });
```

Also, maybe you dont need to update the UI in every iteration, but only for every 10 or 100

```
 if !(i % 10) {
    // update UI progress bar
 }
```

Comment: I like that trick, since the progressBar can be updated animatedly. I'll give it a try, and get back to you (tomorrow)

Comment: @Sjakelien did you come to a conclusion on this?

Comment: Well, yes. I decided, that feedback, albeit slower, is better than no feedback. Your approach works, in a way, so I will vote this as an answer, but it doesn't actually give a smooth experience, since the speed of animation is not representative for the actual speed it should indicate, if that makes sense: you can easily see, that it is chopped in steps.
All in all, since the progress bar represents a background task, the UI remains fully functional, so the user doesn't have to wait for anything.